# Creating specific list of Items for each file in a Directory using C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a List for every file available in a directory. Each file must have a separate list of items. I have created a list, but it shows all items available in all files. How to do it? Need help in this regard. 
I am doing it like this, but it shows all Items "Product" in all files:
a piece of code is here:
 List products = new List();

```
    foreach (string file in fileList)
    {

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                rows++;
                if (line.StartsWith("Product"))
                {
                    var val = line.Split(',');

                    upc = val[1];
                    pName = val[3];

                    products.Add(upc);
                    products.Add(pName);

                    productList = string.Join(",", products.ToArray());
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: `I am trying to create a List for every file available in a directory. Each file must have a separate list of items.` I honestly don't understand

Comment: You could use `var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);` to get array of files in this folder. Hope this helps.

Comment: You need to write code for this. Did you write? Can you share that code and tell us how it is not working and what issue you are facing in that?

Comment: I have 4 '.txt' files in C: Directory, from where i need to read that file and if an Item found in file add it to list, e.g. i have 4 files in folder it must create 4 List<items>, each list for single file.

Comment: So where is the problem? What is "item"?

Comment: "Product" is an item, and every row starts with word "Product" should be added with "UPC" and "pName" in the List<Product>. Here i have problem that it is reading all files and adding all "Products". But i want it to add it separately for each file. e.g. List1 must be equal to File1 and so on.

Comment: Move `List products = new List();` inside foreach loop and you will have list for file. Of course you will have to store list of products per file somewhere (Dictionary or something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these clases

```
public class ProductFile
{
    public string Name;
    public List<Product> Products = new List<Product>();
}

public class Product
{
    public string Upc;
    public string PName;
}
```

And then, in your code:

```
var productFiles = new List<ProductFile>();
foreach (string file in fileList)
{
    var productFile = new ProductFile(){ Name = Path.GetFileName(file) };
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
    {

        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            rows++;
            if (line.StartsWith("Product"))
            {
                var val = line.Split(',');
                var product = new Product()
                {
                    Upc = val[1],
                    PName = val[3]
                };
                productFile.Products.Add(product); //Adds a product
            }
        }
    };
    productFiles.Add(productFile); //Adds a file
}
```